# Value of type 'NSArray' has no member 'indices'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a separate struct which holds my array of quotes, I imagine that I will be adding up to 100 quotes and wanted it in a separate file. I am attempting to access this array from my HomeScreen view controller however keep getting the error "Value of type 'NSArray' has no member 'indices' ". I am beginning to think I have not taken the correct approach to achieve this.

```swift
class Quotes: NSObject {    
    let quotes: NSArray = ["quote1", "quote2","quote50", "quote100"]    
}

class HomeScreen: UIViewController {
    var quotes: NSArray = NSArray()

    func getNextQuote(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.integer(forKey: "savedIndexKey")
        let currentIndex = defaults.integer(forKey: "savedIndexKey")
        var nextIndex = currentIndex+1
        nextIndex = quotes.indices.contains(nextIndex) ? nextIndex : 0 //error here
        defaults.set(nextIndex, forKey: "savedIndexKey")
        let savedInteger = defaults.integer(forKey: "savedIndexKey")
        saved = savedInteger
        quotesLabel.text = quotes[savedInteger]  
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    var quotesArray: Quotes = Quotes()
    quotes = quotesArray.quotes
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `NSArray` in Swift anyway? Swift's Array do have `indices` but `NSArray` might not

Comment: `NSArray` doesnt have a member `indices`. if `count-1` is bigger than some `index`, it surely contains `index`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `NS...` collection types in Swift at all.

Replace

```
let quotes: NSArray = ["quote1", "quote2","quote50", "quote100"]
```

with

```
let quotes = ["quote1", "quote2","quote50", "quote100"]
```

and replace

```
var quotes: NSArray = NSArray()
```

with

```
var quotes = [String]()
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, should I also not be using NSObject?

Comment: @soRazor If you don't need to use your Swift class in Objective-C it is better to avoid using NSObject (until you don't have that requirement, i.e. from protocol)

Comment: You don't need `NSObject`, not even a class. A struct is sufficient.